# Remove one column for a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension (48, 366, 3) and I want to remove the last column from the array to make it (48, 365, 3). What is the best way to do that? (All the entries are integers. I'm using Python v2.6)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could try `numpy.delete`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

or just get the slice of the array you want and write it to a new array.

For example:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(48,366,3))
b = np.delete(a, np.s_[-1:], axis=1)
print b.shape # <--- (48,365,3)
```

or equivalently:

```
b = np.delete(a, -1, axis=1)
```

or:

```
b = a[:,:-1,:]
```

Answer (score 5):

Along the lines:

```
In []: A= rand(48, 366, 3)
In []: A.shape
Out[]: (48, 366, 3)

In []: A= A[:, :-1, :]
In []: A.shape
Out[]: (48, 365, 3)
```