# How to delete a column in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

my array look like this (9 columns)

```
[('2012-07', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '149', '16 TO 18', 150., 1995,'apt', 1000000)
 ('2012-10', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '194', '22 TO 24', 163., 1987, 'ma',  1010000)
  ('2014-12', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '190', '19 TO 21', 150., 1987, 'ma', 1000000)] 

print(a.shape)
output >> (3,)
print(len(a))
output >> 3
```

I want to delete the last 2nd column, so it will look like this

```
[('2012-07', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '149', '16 TO 18', 150., 1995, 1000000)
 ('2012-10', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '194', '22 TO 24', 163., 1987, 1010000)
  ('2014-12', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '190', '19 TO 21', 150., 1987, 1000000)]
```

I tried the np.delete function:

```
b = np.delete(a,7,axis=1)

Error >> AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

My array has multiple rows with 9 columns, just want to delete one column.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove one column for a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710684/remove-one-column-for-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you have a **structured** *Numpy* array.

It must be created with *dtype* parameter, otherwise all field types are *U...*
(Unicode strings of certain size).
I created such an array running:

```
a = np.array([
    ('2012-07', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '149', '16 TO 18', 150., 1995, 'apt', 1000000),
    ('2012-10', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '194', '22 TO 24', 163., 1987, 'ma',  1010000),
    ('2014-12', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '190', '19 TO 21', 150., 1987, 'ma',  1000000)],
    dtype='U7, U3, U10, i4, U10, f4, i4, U4, i4')
```

Note that even if you didn't pass field names (only types like above), *Numpy*
still assigns default filed names, as *f0*, *f1* and so on.

To print field names you can run e.g. `a.dtype.names`. In the above case I got:

```
('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8')
```

so probably your task is to delete *f7* field (check in your environment).
Maybe you have some field names explicitely assigned by your code, so use
the last but one name instead.

To get a copy of a *Numpy* array with this column dropped, you can run:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rcf
b = rcf.drop_fields(a, 'f7')
```

or save it back under *a* if you wish.

**A remark concerning the solution proposed by *Jason Yang*:**

If you run `b.shape` you will get `(3, 9)`, whereas your sample contains
`(3,)` and the array which I created has just this shape.

So your array must have been created some other way than in his solution.

Answer (score 3):

a.shape : (3,), it means there's only 3 element on axis 0, no axis 1. Should check how your matrix data assigned to a.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [('2012-07', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '149', '16 TO 18', 150., 1995, 'apt', 1000000),
     ('2012-10', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '194', '22 TO 24', 163., 1987, 'ma',  1010000),
     ('2014-12', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '190', '19 TO 21', 150., 1987, 'ma',  1000000)]

b = np.array(a)

c = np.delete(b,7,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422982/3944322) is correct for a regular array it doesn't answer the question in the OP which is for a **structured array**. In this case you may create a new array with just the columns you need, i.e. instead of deleting the unwanted column you select the wanted columns.

Example to delete the seventh column:

```
b = a[list(a.dtype.names[:7] + arr.dtype.names[8:])]
```

You can also use the helper function `drop_fields`:

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn
b = rfn.drop_fields(a, a.dtype.names[7])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output from  :

```
print(a.shape)
output >> (3,)
```

shows that the numpy array is 1-dimensional. It has 3 rows and 0 columns.

According to what you want, `shape` should return `(3,9)` denoting 3 rows and 9 columns.

Here is how you can do that :

```
import numpy as np

original_array = np.array([('2012-07', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '149', '16 TO 18', 150., 1995, 'apt', 1000000),
            ('2012-10', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '194', '22 TO 24', 163., 1987, 'ma',  1010000),
            ('2014-12', 'abc', 'EXECUTIVE', '190', '19 TO 21', 150., 1987, 'ma',  1000000)])
```

To delete the second last element, you can use `negative index` :

```
new_array = np.delete(my_array, -2, axis=1)
```